# SQL Server create user, that can use all dbs but sa can restrict him on some db

Tags: sql-server

I need lock functionality on db to some user, while sa making changes on this db.

Example:

user create some databases:

```
database1
database2
database3
```

As `sa` i want to restrict user to making changes in `database1`, but user can still make changes in `database2-3`.

```
ALTER DATABASE database1 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

isn't an option.

upd. Why isn't an option? Because:

I execute `ALTER DATABASE database1 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` from java code using hibernate -> i got lock, ok. But when transaction commits other user can connect to database. I want do something like:

```
1. acquire lock
2. do anything, even restart my java application
3. release lock
```

Comment: 1) why isn't it an option 2) You can change a user's or group's rights, eg giving them data_reader or on privileges for a single database. This is a security, not a programming question

Comment: Create new login and user(for each db) and grant that login to access only that two DB's

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 1. see upd to question 2. can you provide working example as answer and i accept it.

Comment: @knkarthick24 not an option, but of course not too bad workaround

Comment: This is the wrong question to what is actually a concurrency problem. What is your real problem? Why do you want to lock other users out? This is a definite smell, as databases are meant to serve thousands of concurrent users without requiring lockouts. In fact, ORMs should use optimistic concurrency so that even when they do use transactions, they stay open for a very short time. ORMs should *never* be used for heavy batch processing, eg for generating reports. Reports should NOT hit live databases, they should use replicas or their own reporting databases which are populated periodically.

Comment: This is not about concurrency, and high load. This is about synchronization between systems. We need to lock users while we updating almost whole database.

Comment: Simple answer is if user is administrator/SA he can make changes to any database and can do any SQL Server related task you cannot stop him.

Comment: So for now only one solution which really works - create user for each db.